# Clustering / Grouping on image's pixels

Tags: classification, conv-neural-network, image-processing, data-preprocessing

I have an image, and im building a model to recognize a pattern in that image and classify it. There is however a lot of noise in the rest of the image, but the actual pattern to classify will always be the biggest continuous figure in the whole image.
I want to pre process to isolate this bit, before running it in something like a CNN, and I was wondering if standard libraries had an algorithm that was able to find this 'longest non-zero streak' in my image matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing seems to fall under [image segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation). There are many algorithms for it, some listed on wikipedia page (actually some of them perform clustering on pixel values). If you're interested in using deep learning for that, you can check out kaggle, since there are many competitions on segmentation, and you can find architectures and pretrained models there.

If you're interested in Python, you might want to check out scikit-image. It even has a [tutorial on image segmentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/tutorial_segmentation.html).

Comment: Would rather do it as a simpler pre processing before pushing it to my Neural Net. Any of those come out of the box? Couldn't find any on sklearn or numpy.

Comment: I've included a link for an implementation in my answer.

Comment: Amazing, I'll look it up. For the record I voted up, but too noob on this channel to notice

Comment: No problem, good luck. Would you consider editing question title to something like "clustering/grouping on image's pixels"? It might be more useful if someone had a similar question (dbscan is pretty specific).